# How to fix Windows 10 Start Menu from hanging?

Tags: windows, startmenu

My start menu hangs if I search for anything with more than three letters. I looked for solutions online and the suggestions I got were:

1. To enable background apps and restart the system (I tried)
2. To open Powershell and type in `sfc /scannow` to check if there are any corrupt files(The process returned no errors)
3. Restart the Explorer in the Task Manager (First thing that I tried)

I have the latest updated version of Win 10. I didn't have this problem when I first updated it to the Creator's Update version. This problem has been occurring only recently.

Is there any method which might help fix this hanging problem or is there something really silly that I am missing?

Comment: Is the search indexer functioning properly? Maybe try rebuilding the index?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, but I tried troubleshooting Search and Indexing using the in built troubleshooter and then it worked for a couple of times. I tried again and now it gets stuck occasionally.

Answer (score -2):

Try running the following command from and Admin Powershell Prompt...

```py
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```